# want to seperate Footer from container in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to seperate my whole footer from my container in css, when I put a background image for my footer it doesn't appear, and my footer is stuck to the container background

here is the html :

```html
<div id="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div id="colophon">
        <div id="site-info">
            <p>© 2012 <a href="http://localhost/oasis/" title="Oasis" rel="home">Oasis</a>. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div><!-- #site-info -->
        <div id="site-generator">
            <p>
                Powered by <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Semantic Personal Publishing Platform" rel="generator">WordPress</a> and <a href="http://blankthemes.com/">Blank Themes</a>.
            </p>
        </div><!-- #site-generator -->
    </div><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #footer -->
```

And here is my CSS for both container and footer:

```
/* container */
#container { 
    background: url(images/content%20bg.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content-box {}

/* footer */    
#footer {
    background: url(images/fp_bg.gif) scroll; position: relative; top: 100px;
}

#footer #site-info {
    float: left;
}

#footer #site-generator, #footer #footer-right-side {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying a width for your footer since you separated it from your container. Just declare a width and positioning for your footer and it should work fine.

```
#footer {
    width:940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: it didn't actually , stil stuck to the container bg

Comment: @ShehabAbd-Allah Mmm, define stuck? As in, connected? Try adding `margin-top:20px` and see if they separate.

Comment: i ment abwt stuck that the footer texts is inside the container background (( connected yea , and btw no position workin for it :S...

Comment: @ShehabAbd-Allah Ok, lets try to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) this thing out. I made a fiddle with your code and an image i found online, and your problem is that the background is not appearing.  Can you try to replicate your page in this fiddle? its working just fine with the image i used: http://jsfiddle.net/CcFeb/

Comment: Thx Andres , your answer were very helpful to me, apprciate it :))